# Bloated boolean return functions

Tags: oop

Although I'm not sure if I've chosen the right name for it, anyone who's worked on a large project with lots of features has probably seen it: some boolean return function gets bloated with the interaction of every little feature. Eventually what was once a simple one or two variable check becomes:

```
public boolean showFavoritesTool(UserData userData){
    if(currentPage.isPremiumPage())
    {
        return true;
    }

    if(!userData.isLoggedIn())
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(userData.isMember())
    {
        return userData.getPreferences().isFavoritesTurnedOn();
    }

    if(getUrlParams()["showFavorites"])
    {
        return getUrlParams()["showFavorites"]
    }

    return false;
}
```

Edit: Let me clarify, this is just an early example of functions like this. At some point, it would grow as new features are developed to at least twice this size. The function I was looking at that prompted this question had at least 15 variables, some of which were nested. This code may look simple, but it won't remain so as new variables are added.

Everytime a new feature is added, another entry is thrown into the flag function. They don't usually overlap, but when they do you can be sure that no one has thought about what should happen. It doesn't take long before these functions become hard to interpret.

Is there a cleaner solution to this? Also, if that cleaner solution involves more architecture, when would one implement it? As soon as a second variable is added? Or is there some breaking point?

Comment: As long as you're not duplicating code, this looks fine to me. I can read it and immediately understand what's going on.

Comment: What language? C# or Java? You used both tags.

Comment: I have an upvote waiting for the first answer to mention the [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern)

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I'm fine with solutions in either. I've encountered this  scenario in both languages.

Comment: @Raidil142 then i would remove c# and java tags since it's not related to the two languages.

Comment: @MattDavey I hadn't heard of the Specification Pattern until now. I think that would tie into Daniel Brückner's approach very well, where you list the business cases at the start as specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just rewrite it in a more conscious and understandable form. This requires some care because early returns, (double) negations and the like often obscure the behavior and it is easy to introduce bugs.

```
public boolean showFavoritesTool(UserData userData)
{
   return currentPage.isPremiumPage()
       || userData.isLoggedIn() && userData.isMember() && userData.getPreferences().isFavoritesTurnedOn()
       || userData.isLoggedIn() && getUrlParams()["showFavorites"];
}
```

If the logic becomes is really complex it helps introducing some intermediate variables.

```
public boolean showFavoritesTool(UserData userData)
{
   var isPremiumPage = currentPage.isPremiumPage();
   var isLoggedIn = userData.isLoggedIn();
   var isMemberAndHasFavoritesTurnedOn = userData.isMember() && userData.getPreferences().isFavoritesTurnedOn();
   var urlIndicatesShowFavorites = getUrlParams()["showFavorites"];

   return isPremiumPage
       || isLoggedIn && isMemberAndHasFavoritesTurnedOn 
       || isLoggedIn && urlIndicatesShowFavorites;
}
```

In this example it is a bit to much but you get the idea. It is usually a good idea to align  the meaning of intermediate variables with business or technical requirements.

Comment: Do you think you would continue to use a solution like this as the function and complexity grows? For example, the function I was looking at that prompted this question is 60 lines long (white space truncated) and uses over 15 variables to make its boolean decision. This includes some conditional nesting (but not much).

Comment: If the logic is complex then the logic is complex. It will not just go away by pushing it around. In this case the real task is to write it in an understandable and maintainable way. You have to find a compromise between having all the logic in one complex method and spreading the logic across several simple methods, but there is no silver bullet. There is probably some structure in the decisions and you can move parts of it to helper methods similar to my intermediate variables. But don't overdo this, otherwise you will have a showFavoritesTool method but no clue how it makes the decision.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is rather general and it is difficult to understand its scope, nevertheless I will try and provide some insight which will hopefully answer it.

> Everytime a new feature is added, another entry is thrown into the flag function. They don't usually overlap, but when they do you can be sure that no one has thought about what should happen

This is a nasty side effect of poor planning and design. [**Code should be closed for modification, but open to extension**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)

Design with the future in mind, as mentioned previously by Yuval Itzchakov, an interface which contains an abstract `showFavouritesTool()` method which is overriden by each user class depending on each classes requirements will provide greater flexibility, and adhere to the Open/Closed principle. Unfortunately, with the limited information given, it would be difficult to create an example which fits your problem.

Incidently, there will be occassions where multiple boolean expressions need checking. Why not simplify the method by using one concise statement.

For example:

```
public boolean showFavoritesTool(UserData userData){
       return currentPage.isPremiumPage()
              || userData.isLoggedIn() && userData.isMember() && userData.getPreferences().isFavoritesTurnedOn()
              || userData.isLoggedIn() && getUrlParams()["showFavorites"];
}
```

Comment: Apologies to Daniel, who already mentioned refactoring the method to be more concise, I would not have mentioned that had I seen his answer.

Comment: +1 for open closed principle. I think the specification pattern would be the best way to achieve that.

Comment: @MattDavey Definitely! The specification pattern seems like the most relevant design pattern for this question, I should have mentioned this in my answer. Thanks Matt.

Comment: I don't think the specification pattern is of much help here. It is just a fancy way to rewrite and package the rules. You can get a similar modularization by splitting the code into several methods and avoid the overhead of the pattern. The real power of the pattern comes into play when you want to pass rules around or build them dynamically but I see no need for that here. IMHO the core problem is that many different objects have an opinion on whether the answer is true or false and therefore what really is needed is a way to identify these objects and handle them in a unified way.

Comment: You need a way to identify all the objects that have an opinion, ask them for their opinion and finally combine the opinions probably taking into account some kind of priorities. Whether you get the different opinions by calling methods of a common interface or by retrieving a specification rule seems secondary to me.

Answer (score 0):

If all the validations stay in the same place, are clear (for example, take the ! out of the second if and make it a return true, put the return value in the third if and make it a return true also, same with the last if) and commented when "favorites tool" should be shown, I don't see a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a bit too general, since i don't fully understand the scope of the problem. there are multiple uses of fields which we have no knowledge about.

But in general, if you are trying to categories which set of features you want to expose to a group of users, you could make them all inherit a base type, which has an abstract method with a function called SetFavoriteTool, like so:

```
public abstract class BaseData
{
    public abstract bool ShowFavoriteTool();
}

public class UserData : BaseData
{
    public override bool ShowFavoriteTool()
    {
        if ....
    }
}
```

or if you're more into interfaces, you could depend on an IFavoriteTool:

```
public interface IFavoriteTool
{
    bool ShowFavoriteTool();
}

public class UserData : IFavoriteTool
{
    public bool ShowFavoriteTool()
    {
        if..
    }
}
```

and then you could change your method to:

```
public bool ShowFavoriteTool(UserData userData)
    {
        var favoriteTool = (IFavoriteTool) userData;
        return favoriteTool.ShowFavoriteTool();
    }
```

This is just a lead since i don't really understand the Domain problem you're dealing with.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's known as "code rot." It's a process of source degrading in performance and/or maintainability. Eventually it may degrade to a point where the performance gets so bad or it becomes so unmaintainable that you have to start over (version 2.0)

Code rod occurs as a result of incremental enhancements or bug fixes that causes your design veer further and further away from the original design.

To combat code rot, you need to have (and enforce) good standards. Have code reviews, code audits, document source, write unit tests, etc.

Comment: I hadn't heard the term "code rot" before now, and I think this all sounds accurate. While code reviews and unit tests help it remain clean, the still has to eventually support this functionality. Do you have any suggestions for an incremental design that isn't as easily afflicted with code rot?

Comment: It's really a matter of cost vs maintainability. Most of the time, the waterfall approach is too costly (edit requirements, edit design, re-factor to design).  It's more cost effective (at least sort term) to follow a more agile approach and try really really hard to write code that's clean, modular, and easy to read. Writing clean code, however, does nothing for code-rot in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

I will occasionally create my own enum to declare the state of the object. In this case, something similar to this:

```
public enum FavoriteToolState {
    IsVisible,
    IsHidden
}
```

This way, you could set the state of the favorite inside the inner methods which actually determine whether or not the favorite is premium, or whether the user has logged in, or any of those other options, and instead of checking each of those methods, you could check to see if the current FavoriteToolState is FavoriteToolState.IsVisible.

Whether or not this is cleaner could be argued either way, I suppose. I prefer this way in some cases.